# How to solve admin grid error?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, admin, collection, grid

I am getting this error in admin custom module of Magento 2.

> Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have
>   restored the filter to its original state. admin grid error.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? :)

Comment: Please post code here from xml file of UI component

Comment: I am also getting this error. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Please update the answer once you find the solution. I'm also getting the same error on 2.3

Comment: facing same issue with Magento2.3.2

Comment: How do I subscribe to answers to this question... Don't know, so leaving a comment here.

Answer (score 7):

You have to delete an order grid entry from the **ui_bookmark** table.
In a **ui_bookmark** table, delete the row where you want to reset the filter.

or if you don't know which entry of order then you can truncate this table.

Comment: followed ur answer but no luck could you please advise is there any alternative way to fix this issue?

Comment: after truncate facing same issue with Magento2.3.2

Comment: me also facing same issue after truncating this table

Comment: This SQL command fixed it for me `UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET sku='' WHERE sku IS NULL;`

Comment: After deleting the grid column data , refresh cache and check.

Comment: thanks , is working

Answer (score 1):

I also had issue just now with Magento CMS Page Grid, and it was because the JSON response from **/mui/index/render/** Ajax request was invalid.

Fixing the JSON response fixed the issue for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell us how you did this?

Comment: Sander van Zuidam, I did this for a custom ui grid error using the browser console: I opened the console and scrolled down to the GET ... mui/index/render... part and opened the response which, in my case, led to an error of the form {"error":"CustomModel with id "34769" does not exist.", "errorcode":"0"} and worked from there.

Answer (score 1):

After I created some custom modules, I found this error appear when my database table has column named "**order**" and I want to show the "**order**" in the admin grid listing.

Use table column named "order" in Magento2 will issue some unpredictable errors in some other situation too, like collection filter. This is a bug I saw someone post it to official Magento github, but it seems not be fixed in Magento2.2.2 :(

To fix the problem, you have to **rename the table column "order"** to other name, like "sequence".

Hope my answer will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out i had products with no SKU, so this fixed it for me instead of having to truncate `ui_bookmark` table each time:

`UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET sku='' WHERE sku IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but I think this can help.
I also faced this type of issue in my custom module(in all environments local, staging and production) which was working perfectly fine few days ago.
I tried all possible solutions but it is still showing error

> ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT in console for mui/index/renderer

and

> Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state. in grid

Later I found this issue is occurs only in Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be related to session size. If you see this in your system.log

`report.WARNING: Session size of 271683 exceeded allowed session max size of 256000.`

then you should increase the admin max session size like this:

`bin/magento config:set -c system/security/max_session_size_admin 512000`

This solved for me in Magento 2.4.3-p1.