# Magento 2 orders grid not loading

Tags: magento2, orders, order-grid

We have migrated data from M1 to M2.3.1 EE successfully but facing an issue below when open orders grid at magento2 admin end.

> Attention Something went wrong.
>       Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.

Followed below reference links but no luck can anyone suggest me on this.

[Magento2 Error: "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state" showing on the loop](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232021/magento2-error-something-went-wrong-with-processing-the-default-view-and-we-ha)

[How to solve admin grid error?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198543/how-to-solve-admin-grid-error?rq=1)

[Sales Order Grid is empty after data migration process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92551/sales-order-grid-is-empty-after-data-migration-process)

http://www.degtil.com/2017/05/03/magento-2-fixing-a-faulty-grid-filter-something-went-wron

Comment: The issue you are having is down to a 3rd party extension which is installed, can i make the suggestion of going through your extensions and finding out which one is implementing a change to the order grid and disabling it to make sure once you have determined the cause of the issue it would be easier to provide you with a more in depth solution.

Comment: @DavaGordon i will check and get back to you thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

After migrated try to do reindex

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Still if you facing the problem then install the patch

> ./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply MDVA-34330